# Android: Relative Layout set TextView below of another textview and centered

Tags: android, xml

This is my first ask on StackOverflow. a Greetings.

I am using Android Studio, I'm trying to make a Layout that the textView is just below and centered on another TextView. Actually, I have it like this.

[image: current layout]

Want to ask how I can do something like this:

[image: layout that i want]

To center it and be "responsive" with the superior text view. Thank you so much.

this is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPartidasRecomendaciones"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_star" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_perfil_partidasJugadas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imgPartidasRecomendaciones"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Partidas"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textColor="#727272" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_perfil_recomendaciones"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv_perfil_partidasJugadas"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Recomendaciones"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textColor="#727272" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_partidasJugadasNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_perfil_partidasJugadas"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imgPartidasRecomendaciones"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="#212121"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_recomendacionesNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_perfil_partidasJugadas"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv_partidasJugadasNumber"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="#212121"
            android:textSize="20sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and [the tagging guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to wrap each pair of `TextView`s inside a vertical `LinearLayout`:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPartidasRecomendaciones"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_star" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imgPartidasRecomendaciones"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_perfil_partidasJugadas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Partidas"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textColor="#727272" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_partidasJugadasNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="#212121"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rightLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/leftLayout"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_perfil_recomendaciones"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Recomendaciones"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textColor="#727272" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_recomendacionesNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="#212121"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, that is just that i want to, didnt know i had to wrap it. I will learn constraint layout for next designs, thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

You can put every pair of textViews inside  vertical LinearLayout but you better use [constraint layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) - it is a better layout for responsive screen building and easy to integrate with, here is a good example of using it:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@color/buttonColor"
        android:text="view"
        android:textColor="@color/textMainColour"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@color/buttonColor"
        android:text="view"
        android:textColor="@color/textMainColour"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/buttonColor"
        android:text="view"
        android:textColor="@color/textMainColour"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/buttonColor"
        android:text="view"
        android:textColor="@color/textMainColour"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="55dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="146dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@color/buttonColor"
        android:text="view"
        android:textColor="@color/textMainColour"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView4" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest multiple layouts ([LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear?hl=pt-br), [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative), [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout)) to achieve what you want.

If I understand what you asked, you are probably looking for something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:padding="16dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPartidasRecomendaciones"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rl1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rl1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_perfil_partidasJugadas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Partidas"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textColor="#727272" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_partidasJugadasNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_perfil_partidasJugadas"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="#212121"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rl2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rl2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_perfil_recomendaciones"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Recomendaciones"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textColor="#727272" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_recomendacionesNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_perfil_recomendaciones"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="#212121"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I suggest you to use [Constraint Layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) to build better responsive layouts (easier).